# I want to add data-nosnippet="true" to every div in a React app, how can I make it plugin-way?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, plugins

I have a NextJS app, and I'm required to add nosnippet tag to everything except page main description.

I think it would be easier to write a plugin (webpack?) than adding the same string over and over again.

Is it possible?